# An intuitive explanation for two applications of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, law-of-large-numbers

I encountered the following two questions in a measure theory class:
(1) Suppose that I flip a coin many times, and the probability that the coin turns heads on the $n^{th}$ flip is $\frac{1}{n}$. Will the coin ever stop flipping heads?
(2) The same setup as above, but the probability that the coin turns heads on the $n^{th}$ flip is $\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}$, where $\varepsilon > 0$. Will the coin ever stop flipping heads?

I know that by the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = \infty \implies P(A_n \text{ i.o}) = 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) < \infty \implies P(A_n \text{ i.o}) = 0$ (where in the former the events must be independent). Thus, the answer to (1) is no but to (2) it is yes (given the divergence of $\frac{1}{n}$ but the convergence of $\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}$).

I totally get why this is the case based on application of the theorem. But I am having trouble thinking of it intuitively. Why does even the smallest change in the probability of heads make all the difference in saying that, at some point, the coin will stop flipping heads? Does anyone have an intuitive way to think about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac 1 {n^{1+\epsilon}}$ instead of $\frac 1 {n+\epsilon}$? The latter (the one currently in your question) does not converge for any $\epsilon$. If it is indeed the former (which converges), the "smallest" change in this probability, given a large enough $n$, will make a huge difference.

Comment: Oops, yes. $n^{1+\varepsilon}$ in the denominator. I appreciate the assumption that I had not "do[ne] maths" rather than that I had made a typo. But thank you @player3236, I suppose it boils down to the un-intuitiveness of $\infty$, at times :)

Comment: I think the problem with your intuition is revealed by your writing "even the smallest change in the probability of heads". Even though $\epsilon$ is small, $n^{1+\epsilon}$ is way bigger than $n$ for very large $n$ (and those are the only $n$'s that matter).  In other words, you seem to be thinking in terms of the logarithms of probabilities rather than the probabilities themselves.